# Expo + React Navigation + Vercel: Deep Linking not working

Tags: expo, react-navigation-v5, vercel

I am using expo sdk41, react navigation 5, and vercel to deploy a web-build, built with `expo build:web`.

When I am developing locally, I can deep link, e.g. `http://localhost:19006/sign-in`. However when I deploy it to vercel and assign a domain name to it, the deep linking does not work anymore.

I am already doing the following, which allows deep linking to work in development:

```js
export const linking = {
    prefixes: [Linking.createUrl('/'),
    screens: {
        ...
    }
}
```

**Why is deep linking working in development and not when deployed to vercel?**

I am happy to add more info if needs be.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Running `expo build:web` bundles a SPA and you need to redirect calls to the deployed app to `index.html`. Vercel allows configuring redirects using a `vercel.json` configuration file, placed at the root of a project.

Add a `web/` folder in your Expo root directory and create a `vercel.json` file in the `web/` folder with the following content:

```json
{
  "rewrites": [{ "source": "/(.*)", "destination": "/index.html" }]
}
```

This file will be copied to the `web-build` folder when you run `expo build:web`.

Comment: Do you need to create an index.html or does Vercel handle that?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this by setting the framework in the setting to `create-react-app`